# How can I access deleted parent data in a cascade delete?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

I have three tables, lets call them GrandParent, Parent, and Child. Parent has a foreign key to GrandParent's Primary key set up with a Cascade Delete. Similarly, Child has a foreign key to Parent's Primary key.

I'm currently trying to create a trigger so that whenever a record is deleted in any of the three tables (Grandparent, Parent, or Child), I need to call a Stored Procedure. To complete its work, the Stored Procedure needs the GrandParent's Primary key and the value out of a column on Child.

Currently I'm looking at creating the trigger on Child. My problem is that by the time I get to the trigger running when the trigger is set to "ON DELETE", the values are either gone or inaccessible from the database for the GrandParent, and the Deleted virtual table only has the data for the Child table.

I tried to use a "INSTEAD OF DELETE" trigger, but apparently that can't be used on a table with a Cascade delete.

Is there any way of accessing the data from either GrandParent or Parent in the Child's DELETE trigger? If I could at least get to Parent, I could use the Foreign Key to get what I need from the GrandParent table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [DeletionTrigger] ON [Child] 
    ON DELETE
    AS
         DECLARE @ParentID int
         DECLARE @ApplicationID int
         DECLARE @GPID int

         SELECT @ParentID = ParentID, @ApplicationID = ApplicationID FROM deleted --ApplicationID is the item needed from Child table

         SELECT @GPID = GPID FROM Parent WHERE Parent.ParentID = @ParentID

         EXEC DeletionNotifier @GPID, @ApplicationID
    END
```

Comment: Are you not getting any value in  @ParentID variable?

Comment: ParentID is being filled out, but when I go to get GPID, it fails to find the value unless the table the delete started from was Child.

Comment: You should have a trigger on the GrandParent table. In trigger you can get the values of deleted rows of the table on which the trigger is firing. So here you can access only rows from child table only.

Comment: Doesn't that just give me the reverse problem though? How would I get to the ApplicationID field on the Child table?

Comment: <opinion> My preference is to avoid cascading deletes and triggers that implement similar behavior. Instead I write a stored procedure that will do any needed validation and then delete all of the related data in a single transaction. If anything needs to be logged or otherwise tracked then I have a single place to do it. That also allows me to restrict access to the tables, e.g. deny `delete`, and grant access to the SP as needed. </opinion>